# Understaing the difference between two queries from performance point

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this two version of the same query. Both produce same results (164 rows). But the second one takes .5 sec while the 1st one takes 17 sec. Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
TABLE organizations : 11988 ROWS
TABLE transaction_metas : 58232 ROWS
TABLE contracts_history : 219469 ROWS

# TAKES 17 SEC
SELECT contracts_history.buyer_id as id, org.name, SUM(transactions_count) as transactions_count, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tm.value)) as balancing_authorities 
From `contracts_history` 
INNER JOIN `organizations` as `org` 
ON `org`.`id` = `contracts_history`.`buyer_id` 
LEFT JOIN `transaction_metas` as `tm`
ON `tm`.`contract_token` = `contracts_history`.`token` and `tm`.`field` = '1' 
WHERE `contracts_history`.`seller_id` = '850' 
GROUP BY `contracts_history`.`buyer_id` ORDER BY `balancing_authorities` DESC


# TAKES .6 SEC
SELECT contracts_history.buyer_id as id, org.name, SUM(transactions_count) as transactions_count, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tm.value)) as balancing_authorities 
From `contracts_history` 
INNER JOIN `organizations` as `org` 
ON `org`.`id` = `contracts_history`.`buyer_id` 
left join (select * from `transaction_metas` where contract_token in (select token from `contracts_history` where seller_id = 850)) as `tm`
ON `tm`.`contract_token` = `contracts_history`.`token` and `tm`.`field` = '1' 
WHERE `contracts_history`.`seller_id` = '850' 
GROUP BY `contracts_history`.`buyer_id` ORDER BY `balancing_authorities` DESC
```

Explain Results:
First Query: https://prnt.sc/hjtiw6

Second Query: https://prnt.sc/hjtjjg

As based on my debugging of the first query it was clear that `left join` to `transaction_metas` table was making it slow, So I tried to limit its rows instead of joining to the full table. It seems to work but I don't understand why.

Comment: Hot/cold data differences?

Comment: I think the reason could be, in first query, its join with a table `transaction_metas` while in 2nd query it will not join with all data but only selected from that table.

Comment: @jarlh Sorry Sir. I don't understand what you mean by Hot/Cold data.

Comment: Joining `transaction_metas` does not seem to use an index. Could you try moving `AND tm.field = '1'` to your where clause?

Comment: The first explain has a "Using JOIN buffer (Block nested loop)" which is slow. it's like running nested for(each) loops without a break read ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/nested-loop-joins.html )

Comment: @RolandStarke yes there is index on transaction_metas.contract_token and a unique index on contract_history.token

Comment: Cold data not recently read (on disk), hot data recently read (in RAM.)

Comment: @RolandStarke moving tm.field=1 to where clause seems to make it fast (.7sec) but this removed the rows which didn't have any corresponding row in transaction_meta. I kind of need that.

Comment: Maybe you could get rid of this condition then? or add `WHERE tm.field=1 OR tm.field IS NULL` ... but check if the results are still the one you need. Or strick with your frist query and try to create an index over `transaction_metas.token` and `transaction_metas.field`

Answer (score 0):

Join is a set of combinations from rows in your tables. That in mind, in the first query the engine combines all the results to filter just after. In second case one it applies the filter before it tries make the combinations.

The best case would make use of filter in JOIN clause without subquery.
Much like this:

```
SELECT contracts_history.buyer_id as id, org.name, SUM(transactions_count) as transactions_count, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tm.value)) as balancing_authorities 
From `contracts_history` 
INNER JOIN `organizations` as `org` 
ON `org`.`id` = `contracts_history`.`buyer_id` 
  AND `contracts_history`.`seller_id` = '850'
LEFT JOIN `transaction_metas` as `tm`
ON `tm`.`contract_token` = `contracts_history`.`token`
  AND `tm`.`field` = 1
GROUP BY `contracts_history`.`buyer_id` ORDER BY `balancing_authorities` DESC
```

Note: When you reduce the size of the join tables by filtering with subqueries, it may allow the rows fit into the buffer. Nice trick to small buffer limit.

A Better explication:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: This takes exactly the same time as first query that I had i.e 17.0806 seconds

Comment: You explanation makes sense. and that's the reason I had created the second query. But for some reason, I believe that's something MySql should be doing itself. I mean We have the condition on the main table which limits its record. Shouldn't it be joining these records only to transaction_metas corresponding records using index or something. even if not 17 sec is too much for 58232 rows

Comment: Have you created the foreign keys with Innodb table mode?

Comment: Interesting. Have you run  "describe"? Show us the its result, please

Comment: Do you mean EXPLAIN? if so I have added the links to screenshots of the execution plans, for both the queries in question details.

Comment: Explain, describe, and desc does the same. I've been reading the MySQL Doc for a good explanation:
Using join buffer

Tables from earlier joins are read in portions into the join buffer, and then their rows are used from the buffer to perform the join with the current table.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160613/discussion-between-shayllis-alves-de-sousa-and-ankit).